# Prettier 2.6.2 makes strange changes to the html code

Tags: html, prettier

I am new to prettier. I have this strange phenomena in this HTML, after running prettier:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>X</title>
  </head><!-- ddd --->
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Then i run this command:

```
prettier --write "./src/**/*.{ts,html,scss}"
```

And the result is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>X</title></head
  ><!-- ddd --->
  <body></body>
</html>
```

I have this .prettierrc.json file

```
{
"singleQuote": true,
"trailingComma": "es5",
"endOfLine": "auto",
"bracketSpacing": true,
"printWidth": 120
}
```

Any suggestions why this behavior occurs? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [this option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity)

In command line :

`--html-whitespace-sensitivity ignore`

Or in your `.prettierrc.json` :

`htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: "ignore"`